# If a system of equations is consistent and the determinant of the coefficient matrix is zero does this mean that there are infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out for what constant $a$ the following system has infinitely many solutions:

\begin{align*}
ax+y+z&=0 \\
x+ay+z&=0 \\
x+y+az&=0
\end{align*}

For $a=-2$ and $a = 1$ the determinant of the coefficient matrix is zero and since the rank of the coefficient matrix is the same as the rank of the augmented matrix, does this mean that for these two values there are infinitely many solutions?

More generally, what I want to ask is: does the determinant of the coefficient matrix being zero mean that there can't be unique solutions?

Comment: If there is a non zero solution $(x,y,z)$ there will always be infinitely many : since the system is linear, $(x,y,z)$ being a solution implies that for all $\lambda$, $(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z)$ is a solution. Depending on the rank is the dimension of the space of solutions

Comment: In the case $a=1$, the matrix has rank $1$, and since the global space has dimension $3$, the dimension of the space of all solutions is $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that if a matrix is singular then any equation with at least one solution has infinitely many. Here is one way to see this.

Let $A$ be a singular matrix, so that $Ax=0$ has a nonzero solution $x_0$. Since $A$ is linear, any multiple of $x_0$ is also a solution, as mentioned in a comment. Thus we know at least there are infinitely many solutions to $Ax=0$. The set of such solutions is called the *kernel* of the matrix, and it is actually a vector subspace. This is easy to see; if $Ax=0$ and $Ay=0$ and $a,b$ are scalars, then 
$$A(ax+by)=aAx+bAy=0$$
so any linear combination of two elements of the kernel is still in the kernel.

Let $K$ be the kernel of $A$. Let's say we want to solve
$$Ax=y$$
If a solution exists, we can find at least one by methods you're probably familiar with. Call some solution $x_0$. How do we get the rest of the solutions? Well, if we add an element $k$ of $K$ to $x_0$ we get
$$A(x_0+k)=Ax_0+Ak=y+0=y$$
Hence $x_0+k$ is also a solution.

It turns out that this in fact gives you every solution. Why is that? Again this is because of linearity. Suppose $x_0$ and $x_1$ are both solutions. Then
$$A(x_1-x_0)=Ax_1-Ax_0=y-y=0$$
Hence $x_1-x_0\in K$, and $x_1=x_0+(x_1-x_0)$.

Comment: To the O.P.: There is a non-zero solution to $Ax=0$ iff det($A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear map associated to the matrix. The set of solutions corresponds to the kernel of this linear map, and there results from the *rank-nullity formula*, that the rank of the matrix is the codimension of the kernel.